# return only objects with count more than X

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm not sure how to do this with the entity framework. I got the following:

```
return this.enrollments
                .Where(e => e.em_enrolled == false && e.em_result < _settings.PassMark)
                .GroupBy(e => e.em_subject_id)
                .Select(e => e.em_subject_id)
                .ToList();
```

how do i only retrieve records that are present x times.

Comment: The code you've currently got wouldn't even compile. Think about what you've got after the call to `GroupBy` - you've got a sequence of *groups*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean groups with x or more items?

```
return this.enrollments
                .Where(e => e.em_enrolled == false && e.em_result < _settings.PassMark)
                .GroupBy(e => e.em_subject_id)
                .Where(g => g.Count() >= x)
                .Select(g => g.Key)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: No worries.  @JonSkeet's code has been cleaned up more than mine though - I'd look at his more than mine

Answer (score 7):

I suspect you want:

```
return this.enrollments
           .Where(e => !e.em_enrolled && e.em_result < _settings.PassMark)
           .GroupBy(e => e.em_subject_id)
           .Where(g => g.Count() >= x)
           .Select(g => g.Key)
           .ToList();
```

Note that I've changed the `Select` part to reflect the fact that you want to extract the group key from the group. (I've also avoided comparison with `false`, changing `e.em_enrolled == false` into `!e.em_enrolled`. They mean the same thing of course, but I find the latter more idiomatic in C#.)

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks also for the false inspiration, i didn't know you could do that :) I like it better as well